# Articles before titles

Tags: grammar

I saw this sentence on the internet:

> Leader in the IT industry for the past decade, John Smith brings insight to the fast-changing landscape.

Is this correct?

Are the following two variations also acceptable:

> 1. A leader of the IT industry for the past decade,...
> 2. As a leader of the IT industry for the past decade,...

Comment: Well, someone wrote it so they thought it was correct.  It sounds *incorrect* to me.  Your two alternate examples are much better.

Comment: Where did you get this? Please [edit] your post to provide the source. It might be possible as a title (of an article), maybe. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and [Why You Should Cite Your Source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) for more tips.